# Use or access class instances directly in another class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, instance

I am trying to figure out how to access a class instance in another class in Python.
In the example below I create two classes, `house` and `paint`, and I want to use the dimensions from the `house` class as a variable in the `paint` class:

```
class house:
  def __init__(self, length, width)
     self.length = length
     self.width = width

class paint:
  def __init__(self, color_paint, price):
    self.color_paint = color_paint
    self.price = price * (length * width) # <-- length and width from class house
```

Comment: Which instance's attributes do you want to access? Just pass the instance as a parameter to your constructor(`__init__` method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an instance of `House` class to `Paint` class's initializer :

```
class House:
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width


class Paint:
    def __init__(self, color_paint, price, house):
        self.house = house
        self.color_paint = color_paint
        self.price = price * (self.house.length * self.house.width)

house_obj = House(4, 5)
paint_obj = Paint('blue', 1000, house_obj)

print(paint_obj.price)
```

output :

```
20000   # which is 4 * 5 * 1000
```